# Pattern For At Least 5 digits and 3 letters

Tags: html, pattern-matching

I have been studying patterns for a while now and I see it's not an easy thing to understand.

I have been trying to force the input field to accept at least 5 digits at the beginning and at least 3 letters.

I have gotten the pattern for at least 5 digits at the beginning

pattern="(?=\d{5}).*"

How do I include AT LEAST 3 LETTERS?

Comment: Possible: `\d{5,}[a-z]{3,}`, `\d\d\d\d\d+[a-z][a-z][a-z]+` with `/i` if relevant

Comment: \d{5,}[a-z]{3,}, \d\d\d\d\d+[a-z][a-z][a-z]+  
  Not working.

Comment: The proposal by @Déjàvu is correct according to the information you have provided. If it does not suit your needs, you need to be more specific. Could you give examples why it does not work for you?